# How to place a box below one of the elements present on screen on click when the elements were present by 50 cards using .map() function

Tags: reactjs

I have placed 50 elements on the screen using data.map()
When I click a element, it should open a Component below the clicked element. How should i do so?

Comment: Can you share your code with us please ?  We need to understand exactly what you wants. Give us some more details, like What do you want to open ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.
Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for Minimal, Reproducible Example for getting better answers from community.

Answer (score 0):

your question could have been more clear. Use react [state lift](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

basically you should have a state variable like `selectedCard` and store its `key` or something unique for each card.
  So when you click on the card `onClick={() => this.setState({ selectedCard: cardKey })`

and in `map` function check while rendering `if (cardKey === selectedCard)` show the component in `position: absolute` and specify the `absolute style properties` so that it ll be displayed below your selected card.

Answer (score 0):

Have a state variable that has a unique identifier (probably id or some key) of the clicked element. Then whenever an element is clicked update the state with clicked element's unique Id.

And conditionally render the box for matching element.

```
   const [activeElement, setActiveElement] = useState(null);

   .....

   elements.map(element => (
     <div key={element.uniqId} onClick={() => setActiveElement(element.uniqId)}>
      // element jsx

      {activeElement === element.uniqId && (
         // box jsx
      )}
    </div>
   ))
```